# Plot shape with its control net

Tags: graphing-functions

In "Ming-Jun Lai, Larry L. Schumaker. Spline Functions on Triangulations. Cambridge University Press, 2007, p.64", the author plotted a surface and its corresponded control net:
[image]

For my thesis, i need to plot the same thing. How can i plot an object like this? A shape with its control net and control point. My platform is GNU/Linux 3.13. I can use python, blender or Matlab.

Comment: Sounds more like a coding problem than a math problem. Suggest you find a coding website.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Actually, I thought graphic design was pretty good place but our mod screwed up and migrated here after reading this quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The default workflow for compound renders is: Render 2 separate scenes one for the result mesh and one for thecontrol mesh. Then layer the images on top of each other, with software like Gimp, Imagemagick etc.